# Adding a dialog child workflow to an on-demand workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I was wondering if anybody ran into the same issue as I am facing now.

What I'm trying to do is have a workflow that checks the condition of a field (optionset) of a form. If the field has option 1, 2 or 3 then create new record with certain shared attributes, otherwise start a child workflow. The child workflow is a "Dialog" process, not a "workflow" process which informs the user that the record was not created and why. For some reason I cannot select the dialog workflow from the dropdown list of available child workflows...

Both the parent workflow and the "dialog" workflow process are based on the same entity.

If anybody has any ideas on how I could debug this or any clues in general I would greatly appreciate your feedback.

Thanks for taking the time to read this post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to call a dialog from a workflow (see [here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f348aa9b-27f1-431a-a0dc-8226813ee1a3/call-dialog-process-from-a-workflow-crm-2011?forum=crm)).
Workflows are generally triggered by events.
Imagine the ramifications - which user would receive the dialog and what if no-one was logged in?

One option is to drive everything with JavaScript

- Trigger on change of the option set
- Create the records
- Start the workflow
- [Start the dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx)

  - See the section under the heading "Opening a Dialog Process by Using a URL" on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx)
  - Rather use the URL than showModalDialog or showModelessDialog.

What might work even better is to call an Action from JavaScript. The Action can run synchronously and create all records, start child workflows and dialogs.

A synchronous workflow can stop an event and return an error message to the user, but cannot return success messages - it look like this will not meet your requirements, but [Gareth Tucker](http://garethtuckercrm.com/) has an example [here](http://garethtuckercrm.com/2013/12/06/crm-2013-new-features-using-real-time-workflow-for-validation-rules/).

Comment: Hi Bvrce, Thanks for taking the time to answer my post. I should have added that the parent workflow is an on-demand workflow, and it is bound to and triggered by a custom button I created to be displayed in the form view of the entity in question. Therefore there will always be someone logged in when the button is pressed. Does that change your diagnosis of the issue at all?

Comment: No, the platform will not allow you to call a dialog from a workflow. It is possible to call the dialog from JavaScript, then you can cut the workflow out of the equation and just have the button calling JavaScript that does everything.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you for your feedback - people such as yourself make stackoverflow an awesome community to be a part of.